# Use function from inserted HTML via ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, binding, ng-bind-html

I get a HTML-String from my database and I want to insert this into my AngularJs application via  `ng-bind-html`. I did it like the following:

HTML:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myBindHtml"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.myBindHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlStringToInsert);
```

My HTML (which I want to insert) looks like this:

`<button ng-click="testClickEvent()">TestButton</button>`

The insert works fine.

Now I wrote an function (testClickEvent) which the button should call. This simply outputs a string into the console.

But this part does not work. I guess there is no binding from my inserted HTML to this function. Is there any way to call my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular code will only execute when you run it in the angular context. When you use `ng-bind-html` its generated outside the angular context/scope, so angular events like `ng-click` do not work, you need to rely on pure JS events like `onclick` so refrain from these scenarios and just code them directly on angular due to complexity of solution!

We can avoid `ng-bind-html` when angular events are needed and we need to directly code them in the front end and not from input from databases or other methods

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($sce, $scope) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({
            description: $sce.trustAsHtml('<h2 onclick="console.log(\'hello\')">with onclick item ' + i + '</h2>')
        });
    };
    $scope.items2 = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        $scope.items.push({
            description: $sce.trustAsHtml('<h2 ng-click="console.log(\'hello\')"> with ng-click item ' + i + '</h2>')
        });
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.8.3/angular.min.js" integrity="sha512-KZmyTq3PLx9EZl0RHShHQuXtrvdJ+m35tuOiwlcZfs/rE7NZv29ygNA8SFCkMXTnYZQK2OX0Gm2qKGfvWEtRXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items2" ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I see. Well, I thought this could be the case. My situation is that I have a sidebar where I want to list all input fields. When the user clicks on one of these the focus should be set in the corresponding field in my mask. Since the database validates the values in the field the HTML will never be the same. But I already have an idea how to do this in angular context. Thank you so much :)